# External hdd reconnects after safe removal

Tags: external-hdd, unmount

I have transcend 1Tb external hdd and im running ubuntu 16.04 LTE. My external hdd reconnects after I click safely remove. It does power off but comes back up immediately. How do i get it fixed?